# How do I run xandr command on startup under LXDE, Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.4.0-58-generic?

Tags: xrandr

I have tried to run the following command, for a dual monitor set up, on Uxterm terminal manually once Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.4.0-58-generic has started up and it works fine:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 60&&xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary --mode 1440x900 --pos 0x180 --rotate normal --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1440x0 --rotate normal"
```

Nonetheless, adding this line to the start up applications within LXSession, does not take any effect.

Does anyone have any idea that might help to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you are looking for `~/.config/monitors.xml`. Unfortunately the documentation seems to be missing, but you might be able to configure your screen [like I was able to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304278/primary-display-configuration-during-boot-login/1304283#1304283)

Comment: Thanks, I am running LXDE. I see no monitors.xml file under `~/.config`. Would your suggestion be useful to achieve what I want under Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE?

Comment: Oh, the xml file seems to be used by GNOME exclusively